# Node Express post json body with custom header

Tags: php, node.js, express

Id like to return a custom header such as `"201, 'New Student created'"` but I also have a body to return `{"id":1234,"name":john,"major":English}`

```
app.post('/api/v1/students/', function (req, res) {

          ...
          obj = {
                  "id" : id, 
                  "name" : sname,
                  "major" : smajor,

          };
          ...
          ...
          res.status(201).json(obj);
          res.send('New Student created');
  });
```

using v0.12.0

I believe the header and body need to be within the json obj but i am not sure what the format is

parsing the body and header

```
$resp=curl_exec($ch);                
$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($resp, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($resp, $header_size);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express supports adding custom headers to the [response object](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res) with [`append`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.append).

```
app.post('/api/v1/students/', function (req, res) {
    // Create student code

    // Create the response
    res.append('Created', 'New Student Created');
    res.status(201).json(obj);
});
```

According to these docs you can use [http_parse_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-parse-headers.php) to break your `$headers` string into an associative array that you can iterate through to access your headers that come through your response.

Comment: How would you consume that on php side

Comment: From what I know, you need to split your `$headers` string into an array and then you can iterate through the headers.

Comment: Updated answer to include how to get the headers from your `$headers` string

Answer (score 1):

According to the Express docs, one way is to use the `set()` method to set HTTP headers.

```
res.set('New-Student-Created', 'true');
res.status(201).json(obj);
```

Comment: Express does not suggest using `set()` over `append()`, this is misleading, unless you can provide docs that state otherwise. The difference between them is that `set()` can be used to update one or more headers that already exist as well as adding new ones to the response headers array. `append()` simply updates an existing header with the given value or if the header is new it gets added to the headers array. Additionally as noted in the `append()` docs, calling `set()` after `append()` will reset any header created by `append()` previously.

Comment: The word 'suggest' is just be poor wording on my part. I'm not claiming that using .set() is 'the best' way to go. I'm just suggesting that it is one possible way to go.

Comment: Agreed, I just wanted to point out that Express doesn't encourage one function over the other. The wording implies a "best practice" approach by Express.

Comment: I reworded it so it doesn't sound so 'best practice' like.

Comment: OP and @peteb  Thank you for your insight